# In C# how do I have a socket continue to stay open and accept new data?

Tags: c#, sockets, forms

I have a small Windows Form that when I press a press a button a socket goes into a listen state. I'm sending it data from a client program (just simple text) and my Form displays the information.

I want the program to continue listening for more data until I press a "cancel" button or something.

When I press the listen button again I get an error when I try to bind() the socket.

An invalid argument was supplied

This error only pops up the second time I'm pressing the button. I've tried closing the socket once information is received. And setting the LingerOption to false.

The code that's called when I push the listen button is

```
        s1.Bind(endP);
        s1.Listen(10);
        connected = true;
        Receive();
        s1.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        s1.Close();
```

Anybody have an idea of what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may misunderstand the meaning of Listen.  Listen is not to begin receiving input, but rather to start checking for new connections. Your statement about "listening for more data" suggests you belive that listen is for receiving data, not connections.  "Receive" and "Available" are for checking on and receiving more data.  Listen is for marking the socket as one that receives new connections, and Accept is to begin receiving from a new connection.

Comment: Sorry, I guess i didn't express myself properly. I basically want it to able to receive more data. However, your post got me realizing I'm always telling the program to start listening over and over. I added in a flag to see if it's already listening and not to bother listen() if it's already doing so. Now I can get it to hear from different connections as many times as I want, but not to the same connection over and over.

Comment: If you want to receive more data on the socket, don't shut it down.

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind a single socket to a port using regular socket APIs. You should have a single listening socket which accepts new sockets (And remains listening for new sockets after accepting). You don't receive/send on this listener.

```
 s1.Bind(endP);
 s1.Listen(10);
 while (true) {
     Socket s2 = s1.Accept();
     s2.Receive();
     s2.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(_ipAddress, _port) { ReceiveTimeout = 10 };
NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
networkStream.Write(bytesToSend1, 0, bytesToSend1.Length);
byte[] tmpBytesRead = new byte[1024];
Thread.Sleep(150); 
int totalBytesRead = networkStream.Read(tmpBytesRead, 0, tmpBytesRead.Length);
networkStream.Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).